# #define FOO 1u 2u 4u ... What does 1u and 2u mean?

Tags: c, typedef

I'm working with the HCS12 MCU, and this was part of the library. I'm just wondering what 
the 1U, 2U, 4U, 8U... means in this code. I'm still learning how to use classes, please try to explain things in layman terms.

My guess:
Does this just mean which bit is set as high?
1U = 00000001
2U = 00000010
...

What would this be called?

Thanks

```
    typedef union {
  byte Byte;
  struct {
    byte             :1; 
    byte ADR1        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 1 */
    byte ADR2        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 2 */
    byte ADR3        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 3 */
    byte ADR4        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 4 */
    byte ADR5        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 5 */
    byte ADR6        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 6 */
    byte ADR7        :1;                                       /* Slave Address Bit 7 */
  } Bits;
  struct {
    byte         :1;
    byte grpADR_1 :7;
  } MergedBits;
} IBADSTR;
extern volatile IBADSTR _IBAD @(REG_BASE + 0x000000E0UL);
#define IBAD                            _IBAD.Byte
#define IBAD_ADR1                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR1
#define IBAD_ADR2                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR2
#define IBAD_ADR3                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR3
#define IBAD_ADR4                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR4
#define IBAD_ADR5                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR5
#define IBAD_ADR6                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR6
#define IBAD_ADR7                       _IBAD.Bits.ADR7
#define IBAD_ADR_1                      _IBAD.MergedBits.grpADR_1
#define IBAD_ADR                        IBAD_ADR_1

#define IBAD_ADR1_MASK                  2U
#define IBAD_ADR2_MASK                  4U
#define IBAD_ADR3_MASK                  8U
#define IBAD_ADR4_MASK                  16U
#define IBAD_ADR5_MASK                  32U
#define IBAD_ADR6_MASK                  64U
#define IBAD_ADR7_MASK                  128U
#define IBAD_ADR_1_MASK                 254U
#define IBAD_ADR_1_BITNUM               1U
```

Comment: The `U` indicates the literal should be treated as `unsigned`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It defines an unsigned integer [literal](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fconref.htm). You can also see where they defined a hex literal to be an `unsigned long integer` by using `0x...UL`.

If you would like to know the bit pattern they produce, simply translate the decimal literals to their equivalent hex or binary literals. `1U` becomes `0x01U` and `01b`<sup>1</sup> in hex and binary respectively.

Another more commonly seen literal uses the `f`-suffix, that is a single precision floating point literal like `1.0f`.

<sub>1. for illustration only, not an actual literal per the standard</sub>

Comment: Just a quick question:

when I write:

IBAD &= ~IBAD_IBAD6_MASK; 

I get an error saying "Possible loss of data"

and when I cast it to an int, i no longer get that error.

IBAD &= (int)(~IBAD_IBAD6_MASK); 

Why is this? I've looked into this for an hour, and I cannot find a conclusive answer.

Comment: @user2066639: what is `byte` defined as? Sounds like it is signed.

Comment: I'll start a new question, can't seem to fit this in this text box. Thanks for the help! but for your referece: 

#elif defined(__INT_IS_8BIT__)
  typedef  unsigned int       Byte;
  typedef    signed int       sByte;

Answer (score 3):

They're just integer constants.  The `U` suffix makes them unsigned ints instead of ints.

This is described in section 6.4.4.1 of the [final draft of the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In Embedded systems U literal means that the value is unsigned integer

you can find some usefull content here.

[information for Literals](https://infoc.eet.bme.hu/jegyzet/c_puska.pdf)